# Summing up two options

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-option

Let's say I have two optional Ints (both can be Some or None):

```
val one : Option[Int] = Some(1)
val two : Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

My question is the following: Are there any intelligent way to sum them op using Scalas brilliant collection-methods? I realize that I could merge them into a collection, `flatten` it and use `reduceLeftOption` like so:

```
(one :: two :: Nil).flatten.reduceLeftOption(_ + _)     // Some(3)
```

But, the solution above means creating a new collection, and living in a rich and developed world that takes time from all the other first world activities I might immerse myself into. And in a world where programming gets more and more luxurious for programmers like us, there must be one or more luxurious first world answer(s) to this, right?

Edit: So to spell things out, here are some examples:

If `one = Some(1)` and `two = Some(2)` we should have Some(3)

If `one = Some(1)` and `two = None` we should have Some(1)

If `one = None` and `two = Some(2)` we should have Some(2)

If both `one` and `two` are `None`  we should have None, since neither `one` or `two` can be summed correctly.

Hope that clarified things :-)

Comment: Thanks for the edit Ben James, maybe I'm just old and grumpy but I was having a "first world" headache reading the original version...

Comment: International Worker's day Régis. Once a year. Don't be so petty :-)

Comment: Why remove the International Worker's day comment? You guys have no style..

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188123/is-there-a-name-for-this-kind-of-lifting-a-function :) More info there at least ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

obligatory scalaz answer is to use the scalaz Option monoid:

```
scala> one |+| two
res0: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

It will do what you want with respect to None:

```
scala> two |+| None
res1: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> none[Int] |+| none[Int]
res2: Option[Int] = None
```

That none method is a method from scalaz which helps with type inference because instead of returning `None <: Option[Nothing]` it returns a `Option[Int]`, there is a similar method from Some which returns an Option[A] for any given A instead of a Some[A]:

```
scala> 1.some |+| 2.some
res3: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great! It just seems like slightly overkill to import a new library. I'll accept it if nothing better shows :-)

Comment: Just do it!  scalaz is very first library I add to any project.  Once you start getting used to it, you'll find there are tons of gems in there you won't want to live without :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really looks clean. Looks like I'll have to spend some more time with scalaz :-)

Comment: Here's a nice intro video that starts with monoids from our very own @oxbow_lakes: http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/practical-scalaz-2518

Comment: Thanks! As another option, library cats worked for me. `import cats.implicits._`

Answer (score 25):

```
for (x <-one; y <- two) yield x+y
```

Or the less readable but strictly equivalent:

```
one.flatMap{x=>two.map(x+_)}
```

**UPDATE**: As your latest edit made quite clear, you only want a `None` as the result when both the input options are `None`. In this case I don't think you'll get anything better in terms of simplicity than what you already use. I could shorten it a bit but overall this is just the same:

```scala
(one ++ two).reduceOption(_ + _)
```

Comment: Excellent reply, sir. But if `one` is None, the whole result is None, right?

Comment: Oh, right, you wanted to get 0 in case either option is `None`? Then just add a `getOrElse(0)` at the end. Or better yet, just do `one.getOrElse(0)+two.getOrElse(0)`.

Comment: Actually I would prefer to get None, if both were None. But if the first (one) is None and the second (two) is Some(2) (for instance), I would prefer Some(2). The code above returns None.

Comment: Got it. I think in this case every answer until now is actually incorrect then. That's an uncommon requirement.

Comment: How about `(one ++ two).reduceOption(_ + _)` then? That's basically you own code, only slightly shortened.

Comment: Although I like scalaz, this should be the answer, as it is a straightforward one-liner that requires no external libraries.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
one.map(_ + two.getOrElse(0)).orElse(two)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
for( x <- one.orElse(Some(0)); y <- two.orElse(Some(0))) yield x+y
```

Comment: `one.map(two.getOrElse(0) + _)`  is incorrect: if two is `None` you'll get `Some(1)` instead of None.

Comment: Ya, I caught that and amended my answer