# Is there a name for this kind of lifting a function?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, lifting

I wrote a Scala function:

```
  def liftOrIdentity[T](f: (T, T) => T) = (a: Option[T], b: Option[T]) =>
    (a, b) match {
      case (Some(a), None) => Some(a)
      case (None, Some(b)) => Some(b)
      case (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(f(a, b))
      case (None, None) => None
    }
```

Is there a name for this pattern? It is not quite an applicative functor due to cases 1 and 2. Feel free to answer with Haskell or Scala code.

Comment: On collection it is `flatten` + `reduce`: `List(a, b).flatten.reduceOption(f)`.

Comment: That is pretty sexy! Compared to the wall of ugly above :) Consider posting this as an answer ;) Didn't know about reduceOption, that's pretty slick!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On collection it is `flatten` + `reduce`:

```
List(a, b).flatten.reduceOption(f)
a ++ b reduceOption f // same result
```

Comment: I'll leave it hanging to see if there are more suggestions, but will probably accept this :)

Comment: I chose this answer because it concisely solves the problem. The use of flatten here is very nice, and I didn't know about the "oddly specific" reduceOption, but it works nicely for my problem.

Comment: @Felix: Note that you are actually don't need `flatten` here: `a ++ b reduceOption f`.

Comment: Can you maybe tell me where Option gets its ++ method from? http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option I see it listed, it works in REPL, but it doesnt extend TraversableLike and it doesn't implement it :S I'm confused!

Comment: `Option` has not `++` method. In documentation it has green color and `Implicit information` in description. As you can see from the `Implicit information` there is an implicit conversion [`Option.option2Iterable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option$).

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't read that :) I guess the API sometimes is a bit of an information overload. On another note, if you don't unfold to "Full signature", the signature is just plain wrong right? "def ++[B](that: GenTraversableOnce[B]): Option[B]" doesn't return Option[B]...

Answer (score 7):

I'm reminded of the `Alternative` type class in Haskell's `Control.Applicative`:

```
class Applicative f => Alternative f where
    empty :: f a
    (<|>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
```

A general version of your function for any instance of `Alternative` might look like this:

```
liftOrAlternative :: (Alternative f) => (a -> a -> a) -> f a -> f a -> f a
liftOrAlternative f a b = f <$> a <*> b <|> a <|> b
```

---

```
ghci> liftOrAlternative (+) (Just 1) Nothing
Just 1
ghci> liftOrAlternative (+) (Just 1) (Just 2)
Just 3
ghci> liftOrAlternative (+) Nothing Nothing
Nothing
```

---

For Scala, I think the closest analogy to `Alternative` would be the `ApplicativePlus` type class from Scalaz.

```
 def liftOrAlternative[A, F[_]: ApplicativePlus](f: (A, A) => A)(a: F[A], b: F[A]): F[A] =
   f.lift[F].apply(a, b) <+> a <+> b
```

I admit that `liftOrAlternative` is not a great name. After reading Twan van Laarhoven's answer, I think his suggestion of `unionWith` is much better at expressing what the function actually does.

Comment: There is, but it applies to `Map`s, not applicatives in general.

Comment: Where is the one on `Map`s? The only ones I've seen are on the strongly Haskell-inspired `IntMap` and `LongMap` classes.

Comment: I think you are correct, it is not for `scala.collection.Map`

Answer (score 4):

This function is similar to the Haskell containers function

```
Data.Map.unionWith :: (a -> a -> a) -> Map k a -> Map k a -> Map k a
```

I think unionWith is a good name for it in general. The more usual applicative operator would be an `intersectionWith` (aka. `zipWith`).

```
Data.Map.intersectionWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k c
```

Answer (score -1):

In Haskell, there is something similar called [liftM2](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3aliftM2).

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
```