# How to sum two Option[Float] in scala

Tags: scala

How do I sum two Option[Float] in Scala?

For example:

```
Option[Float](1.5f) + None = 1.5f
Option[Float](2.3f) + Option[Float](1.2f) = 3.5f
```

Of course, the provided example doesn't work since `+` method expects a String

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319505/summing-up-two-options

Comment: From your example it seems you want to get the result as a simple `Float`, not as an `Option[Float]`. In that case the simplest solution is `f1.getOrElse(0f) + f2.getOrElse(0f)`

Answer (score 1):

Either by pattern matching on the tuple:

```
val addOptions = (o1: Option[Float], o2: Option[Float]) => (o1, o2) match {
  case (Some(v1), Some(v2)) => Some(v1 + v2)
  case (None, v@Some(_)) => v
  case (v@Some(_), None) => v
  case (None, None) => None
}

addOptions(Some(1.2f), None)
----
res3: Option[Float] = Some(1.2)
```

, or using Option's `.fold`:

```
val addOptions = (o1: Option[Float], o2: Option[Float]) =>
  o1.fold(o2)(v1 => o2.fold(o1)(v2 => Some(v1 + v2)))
```

Then you can also add n items by passing the function when folding a list.

```
val lst = List[Option[Float]](Some(1.5f), None, Some(2f))
lst.foldLeft(None: Option[Float]) { (acc, item) => 
  addOptions(acc, item)
}
```

You could also use `cats` library (https://github.com/typelevel/cats) or something like it:

```
import cats.implicits._

val a: Option[Float] = Some(2f)
val b: Option[Float] = Some(2f)
a |+| b
----
res2: Option[Float] = Some(4.0)
```

`|+|` is just the combine operator for Semigroups (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup)

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is create a function

```
def add (opt1:Option[Float],opt2:Option[Float]) : Option[Float] = {

  (opt1,opt2) match {
  case (None,None) => None
  case (None,v@Some(_)) => v
  case (v@Some(_),None) => v
  case (Some(v1),Some(v2)) => Some(v1+v2 )

}

}
```

and call with
add(Some(1.5f),None)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` method to get the value of `nonEmpty Option`.

```
scala> Option[Float](2.3f).get + Option[Float](1.2f).get
res0: Float = 3.5
```

If the `Option` is empty then it throws `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

```
scala> Option[Float](2.3f).get + Option.empty[Float].get
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:349)
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
  ... 29 elided
```

So the safest way is to use `getOrElse` as @Kolmar has also commented

```
scala> Option[Float](2.3f).getOrElse(0f) + Option[Float](1.2f).getOrElse(0f)
res2: Float = 3.5

scala> Option[Float](2.3f).getOrElse(0f) + Option.empty[Float].getOrElse(0f)
res3: Float = 2.3
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: @Marcos Rios, didn't it help?

Answer (score 0):

The cats library would make things so much easier in this case but just in case you cannot use it here's a viable alternative:

```
def reduce(v1: Option[Float], v2: Option[Float]): Option[Float] =
    v1.flatMap( x => v2.map(y => x + y).orElse(v1))

def sum(v1: Option[Float], v2: Option[Float]): Option[Float] = {
    if(v1.isDefined)
      reduce(v1, v2)
    else
      reduce(v2, v1)
  }
```

You simply call sum to add two Floats:

```
sum(Some(22),Some(22))
```

You could also simply use a for-comprehension